# Does the following verilog code have a race condition issue?

Tags: verilog, race-condition

I am working with a verilog module (shown below) has two always blocks. Won't there be some sort of race condition since one block sets a register and the other uses the register.  What kind of issues would this cause?

Thanks,
Stephen

```
module XYZ
(                               
    input  wire         CLK,    
    input  wire         Reset,    
    input  wire         nReset,   
    input  wire [15:0]  X,      
    input  wire [15:0]  A,    
    input  wire         T,  
    input  wire         B,  
    output reg          M     
);

assign C = X > A;

reg P;  
reg N;

always @(posedge CLK, negedge nReset)
begin
    if (~nReset)
    begin
        P <= 1;
        N <= 1;
    end else begin
        if (Reset)
        begin
            P <= 1;
            N <= 1;
        end else begin
            P <= T?  1:  ((C & ~M)?  0:  P);
            N <= B?  1:  ((M & ~C)?  0:  N);
        end
    end
end

always @(posedge CLK, negedge nReset)
begin
    if (~nReset)
    begin
        M <= 0;
    end else begin
        if (Reset)
        begin
            M <= 0;
        end else begin
            M <= M?  ~(N & ~C):  (P & C);
         end
    end
end
```

endmodule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no race condition.  Verilog is an event-driven simulator. Posedge (unless there is a glitch in the clock or reset) is usually executed once per the simulation tick. If you use non-blocking assignments correctly (and it looks like you did), every always block triggered by an edge will use old versions of the input variable values, the values which existed **before** the clock edge.

Here is a simplified example:

```
always @(posedge clk)
   r <= in;
always @(posedge clk)
   out <= r;
```

What happens in this situation is the following:

1. `r` will be assigned the value of `in` later at the simulation tick, after the always blocks have been evaluated (see the nba scheduling region).
2. since `r` has not been yet really changed, the `out` will be scheduled to be assigned the value of `r` with the value before the edge.

If `r` was 0 before the edge and `in` was 1, at the end of the simulation `r` will become 1 and `out` will become 0.

This mimics behavior for real flops in hardware.

In your case it might look as a loop dependency. In reality it it none. For the same reason as above the `M` value will be the one from before the the posedge and will not cause any race. Flops cannot be involved in the combinational loops due to their properties logical properties.

Answer (score 1):

I completely Agree with the above answer and i would suggest some more to the above answer, when i started learning Verilog i too got the same doubt and these lines from a ref. book clarified my doubts. I am coping the statement here and 
for further doubts u can comment here or u can see the

- Ref. book page number 135
- Book name :Verilog HDL: A Guide to Digital    Design and Synthesis,
  Second Edition By Samir Palnitkar

> nonblocking statements used in Example 2 eliminate the race condition.
>   At the positive edge of clock, the values of all right-hand-side
>   variables are "read," and the right-hand-side expressions are
>   evaluated and stored in temporary variables. During the write
>   operation, the values stored in the temporary variables are assigned
>   to the left-handside variables. Separating the read and write
>   operations ensures that the values of registers a and b are swapped
>   correctly, regardless of the order in which the write operations are
>   performed.
>   On the downside, nonblocking assignments can potentially cause a
>   degradation in the simulator performance and increase in memory usage.

```
//Example 2: Two concurrent always blocks with nonblocking
//statements
always @(posedge clock)
a <= b;
always @(posedge clock)
b <= a;
```

And u can use this type of coding style not compulsory but for the ease of debugging and to fasten simulation u can reduce the usage of begin-end blocks where ever possible

```
module XYZ
(                               
    input  wire         CLK,    
    input  wire         Reset,    
    input  wire         nReset,   
    input  wire [15:0]  X,      
    input  wire [15:0]  A,    
    input  wire         T,  
    input  wire         B,  
    output reg          M     
);

reg P,N;

always @(posedge CLK, negedge nReset)
    if (~nReset)begin
        P <= #10 1;
        N <= #10 1;
    end else if (Reset) begin
        P <= #10 1;
        N <= #10 1;
    end else begin
        P <= #10 T ?  1 :  ((C & ~M) ?  0:  P);
        N <= #10 B ?  1 :  ((M & ~C) ?  0:  N);
    end

always @(posedge CLK, negedge nReset)
    if      (~nReset) M <= #10 0 ;
    else if (  Reset) M <= #10 0 ;
    else              M <= #10 M ?  ~(N & ~C):  (P & C);

assign C = X > A;

endmodule
```